# Avoid repetition code in Svelte for bind values

Tags: dry, svelte

following this example:

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/select-bindings

I wanted to enhance this example by saving the state of the answer, so I modified the code slightly to achieve this.

But I am worried this will result in a lot of repeated lines in different parts of code, checking if the `selected` value is defined after render.

I would like to move `foundIndex` function outside of `handleSubmit` and `handleChange`, but it throws an error, because the `selected.id` is not defined at the initial 'state'.

See below:

```
<script>
let questions = [
    { id: 1, text: `Where did you go to school?`, answer: "" },
    { id: 2, text: `What is your mother's name?`, answer: "" },
    { id: 3, text: `What is another personal fact that an attacker could easily find with Google?`, answer : "" }
];

let selected;

let answer = '';

function handleSubmit() {
    const foundIndex = questions.findIndex(question => question.id === selected.id);
    questions[foundIndex].answer = answer;
};

function handleChange() {
    const foundIndex = questions.findIndex(question => question.id === selected.id);
    answer = questions[foundIndex].answer || "";
};
</script>

<style>
    input { display: block; width: 500px; max-width: 100%; }
</style>

<h2>Insecurity questions</h2>

<form on:submit|preventDefault>
    <select bind:value={selected} on:change={handleChange}>
        {#each questions as question}
            <option value={question}>
                {question.text}
            </option>
        {/each}
    </select>

    <input bind:value={answer}>

    <button on:click={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>

<p>selected question {selected ? selected.id : '[waiting...]'}</p>
```

Link to REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/5a8cd70dc6664e4b983e1bc729ac953b?version=3.12.0

Comment: Could you post this as a REPL to work from ? I just tried and it seems to work.  I extracted `foundIndex` as `const findIndex = (question) => questions.findIndex(question => question.id === selected.id);`

Answer (score 0):

Move the function, but pass in the questions and selected.id as a parameter.

```
function findIndex(questions, selectedId) {
  return questions.findIndex(question => question.id === selectedId);
}
```

Then call it from your handlers.